# function of GND pin in voltage regulators

Tags: voltage-regulator, pins, negative-feedback

In a voltage regulator what is the function of the GND pin?I thought it was to create a reference voltage for the input/output but I have seen it being fed from the output of the voltage regulator through a voltage dividers so now I am not sure.

Comment: Please give a link to a datasheet showing a GND pin fed from the output as you described. (This connection is common, but when it's used the pin is usually called "ADJ" rather than "GND")

Answer (score 2):

The adjustable  regulators use a ratio of the Vout to 0V back into Vfb to be equal to the internal Vref.

Gnd is simply defined as your 0V reference.

But where you chose that depends on the sense voltage and return current which can introduce voltage drop. When grounds are shared, we must consider the current and rise time if any dynamic loads and choose star grounds from source where they are shared so that 0V is not influenced by those return currents and path impedance.

If it is floating from earth ground then common mode noise must be balanced to minimize the interfacing effects of multiple SMPS on high impedance floating gnds.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it references the regulator to a point in a circuit - typically GND.

If required, non-standard voltages can be generated by connecting the regulator's GND to another reference voltage. e.g. If you needed an 8 V supply you could use a 7805, 5 V regulator with its GND pin held at 3 V.